# :first-child toggle not functioning as expected in wordpress loop

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops, toggle, css-selectors

i have a group of 'question/answer' div pairings where the 'answer' div is hidden and shows when the 'question' div is clicked. the first pair in the set should load with the answer already open. outside of wordpress, this works as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/Y724r/1/

when i get that same code into the wordpress loop though, the last question loads open instead of the first: http://www.htcaz.com/web/?page_id=5  (the pairing titled 'About HTC' is the one who's 'answer' div should be open on load, but its doing the last one instead)

loop:

```
<?php $subpages = new WP_Query("post_parent=5&post_type='page'&orderby=ID&order=ASC");
if($subpages->have_posts()) : while($subpages->have_posts()) : $subpages->the_post(); ?>
   <div class="post">
        <div class="question">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
   </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(".answer").hide();
jQuery(".question").click(function () {
    jQuery(".answer").not(jQuery(this).next(".answer")).hide();
    jQuery(this).next(".answer").toggle();
});
jQuery('.question:first-child').trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this

`jQuery('.question:first-child').trigger('click');`

with

`jQuery('.question:eq(0)').trigger('click');`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery(".answer").hide();
jQuery(".question").click(function () {
    jQuery(".answer").not(jQuery(this).next(".answer")).hide();
    jQuery(this).next(".answer").toggle();
});
jQuery('.question:eq(0)').trigger('click');
});
```

`eq(n)` is the `jQuery` selector get the element by the index no. so on page load you have to `trigger` the click event on first `.question` div

[**Here is your fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y724r/3/)

[**eq(n)**](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: YES you rock! and extra thanks for including the documentation link for further reading :)